# series regrouping

Tags: sequences-and-series

My question is how to prove the proposition below:

First, we will define a regrouping:

***Defintion**: Let $\;{q_1},{q_2}\dots,{q_n} \;  ({q_i}\in\Bbb Q)$ such that $\beta=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n q_i$. We say that a
(non-trivial) **regrouping** of the series is a new series
$\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^N p_j$ where $N\geq 2$, fulfilling:*

1. $p_j=\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I_j} q_i$,$\,$ *with* $\,$
   $\{1,2,\dots,n\} =\displaystyle\bigsqcup_{j\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}}
   I_{j}\;$ *(disjoint union)*
2. $\beta=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^N p_j.$

> ***Proposition**: If we have **n** rational numbers, ${a_1},{a_2}\dots,{a_n} \; \, ({a_i}\in\Bbb Q)$ and others **m**
> rational numbers, ${b_1},{b_2}\dots,{b_m} \; \, ({b_j}\in\Bbb Q)$ ,
> $(n,m)\in \Bbb N, \,$ in such a way that:*
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{j=1}^m b_j$$
>
> *Then there is a regrouping of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ that turns out to be $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^m b_j$.*

Thanks,
Tomás Catuxo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the lemma you are trying to prove is false. Consider $a_1=a_2=a_3=1$ and $b_1=b_2=1.5$

Obviously, $$\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{2}b_i$$

The only possible 'regroupings' of $\sum a_i$ that aren't simply permutations of it are:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{1}p_i\,\,\,\,\text{ where }p_1 = a_1+a_2+a_3 = 3$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2}p_i\,\,\,\,\text{ where }p_1=2\text{ and }p_2=1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2}p_i\,\,\,\,\text{ where }p_1=1\text{ and }p_1=2$$

Neither of these are the same as $\sum b_i$

Essentially, one way in which this ends up being false is that if all the $a_i$ are integers and at least one $b_i$ is a non-integer, that $b_i$ cannot be constructed as the sum of a selection of $a_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the contraexemple

Comment: OK, SEE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718060/series-regroupings-updates TO THE NEW PROBLEM (just in the infinity)