# Series regroupings (updates)

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

First, we will define a regrouping:

***Defintion**: Let $\;{q_1},{q_2}\dots,{q_n} \;  ({q_i}\in\Bbb Q)$ such that $\beta=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n q_i$. We say that a
(non-trivial) **regrouping** of the series is a new series
$\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^N p_j$ where $N\geq 2$, fulfilling:*

1. $p_j=\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I_j} q_i$,$\,$ *with* $\,$
   $\{1,2,\dots,n\} =\displaystyle\bigsqcup_{j\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}}
   I_{j}\;$ *(disjoint union)*
2. $\beta=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^N p_j.$

> ***Proposition (updated)**: If $\;{a_i}, {b_j}\in\Bbb Q,\; \forall i,j\in \Bbb N$ and are such that:*
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j < \infty.$$
>
> *Then, there is a regrouping of $\;\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ that turns out to be $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j$.*

I´m trying to prove this lemma. Any ideas?

Comment: Gaurav proved that if we are adding finite numbers, then the Lemma is false: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717996/series-regrouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this version of the lemma is false as well. We can find a counter-example along similar lines as were used for the [previous version of the lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717996/series-regrouping) you posted.

Consider the sequence $a_n$ defined as $a_1 = 1$, $a_n=0\,\,\,\forall n>1$ and the sequence $b_n$ defined as $b_n = 2^{-n}$

Both sequences sum to $1$ but you cannot construct any $b_i$ as the sum of a selection of $a_i$.

Comment: I forgot to impose that terms can not be 0 beyond a certain range